# Netbeans PHP code completion broken

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion, netbeans-8

In PHP, when I declare class variable like this

```
/**
 * @var \Factories\FormFactory
 */
public $formFactory;
```

& I use it within that class like `$this->formFactory->` the codecompletion works just fine.

[image: working]

But if I try the same in inherited class (not direct descendant) Netbeans still suggests the variable with correct type

[image: only variable completion]

but does not suggest its methods

[image]

Any idea why?
I tried to delete cache to no avail.

Info:

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Java: 1.8.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_11-b12
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1250; cs_CZ (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\Ciki\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0
Cache directory: C:\Users\Ciki\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0

Reported as bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=246217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a Netbeans bug. There is already a similar bug:

[Bug 245129 - Code completion on sub class not correct when returning $this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=245129)

You can sign up in the netbeans bugzilla and open a bug report.

Follow the [Issue Reporting Guideline](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IssueReportingGuidelines) and read the [rules](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IssuezillaRules):

- One problem - One issue
- Provide a meaningful summary
- Provide a detailed description
- Provide steps to reproduce
- Use Attachments

It maybe then help to fix this issue in the next release.